# SwiftUI TabView + NavigationView navbar doesn't show up

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, tabview

I started to use SwiftUI after a couple years of UIKit.. This is not a piece of cake lol.

Alright, so I am trying to build an app that has a tab bar with 2 elements. Each Tab with contain a ViewController (View now) and they will be embedded in a NavigationController (NavigationView now)

The actual result is this
[image]

and I am expecting to have a nav bar with a title set to Home.

Could you explain me what I do wrong here? i followed the documentation and a couple tutorials, and I don't seem to do differently.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            RedView()
                .tabItem({
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                })
                .tag(0)
            BlueView()
                .tabItem({
                    Image(systemName: "dollarsign.square.fill")
                    Text("Trade")
                })
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBarView()
    }
}


struct RedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("test")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
}
struct BlueView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("test2")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Trade")
    }
}
```

This is the file that contains everything at the moment. Thanks in advance for any future help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.navigationBarTitle` should be *inside* `NavigationView`

```
struct RedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("test")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")     // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I am amazed by this rookie mistake! thank you!

Comment: Not related, but, by any change, do you know why on an iPad the view is like this and not taking the full screen, i don't recall using a SplitViewController here. https://i.imgur.com/H299eA8.png

Comment: got it with this: `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`. Thanks again!